# Is there a way to have EKS cluster take images from local system using terraform?

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks

I am creating 3 images on local machine. I am then using terraform on local system through aws cli to create a EKS cluster and node groups on AWS. When I try to deploy the pods on EKS cluster, the pods fail with error:"ImagePullBackOff"- Failed to pull image ""image name": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: pull access denied for "image name", repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied

I dont want to push the images to docker hub. I want to know if there is a way to have the images be pulled by the pods directly from local system?

Comment: I would say that is possible, but not easily. I would suggest to just create ECR repositories.

Answer (score 0):

In EKS, and in Kubernetes in general, you can't pull images from the local machine.  You *must* push them to some repository.  In an AWS context, [ECR](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ecr/index.html) can be a good match.

The only exceptions to this are the single-machine purely-local Kubernetes installations (Docker Desktop, Minikube, Kind) which have some ways to build or import images directly on the single cluster node.  If you're in any sort of multi-node or cloud environment, an image registry is basically required to use Kubernetes.